# How to give a user the rights to "clear cache"

Tags: caching

I need to give a user the ability to "clear cache" since he sometimes does some changes to the menus, etc...  How can I give him a right to do that, or can I just send him a URL or post something on his admin toolbar?  With the roles and rights I've given him so far he can only go to one thing on the Configuration page and that's "URL aliases."  I recall that I used to have a way to accomplish this for the authenticated users with a little block at the bottom of the footer, but I can't find it or remember how I did it..

Help please, and thanks in advance.

Dave N

Answer (score 1):

You may try [UI Cache Clear](https://www.drupal.org/project/ui_cache_clear).

Project page says:

> - Clears specific cache bin without flushing the whole site cache.
> - Allows to clear cache without full administrator permissions.
> - Provides setting to clear current page cache automatically when    clearing Block, Views or Panels cache.
> - Admin menu and Shortcut integration

Answer (score 0):

I have good experiences with [CacheFlush](https://www.drupal.org/project/cacheflush). I especially liked the option that I can define permissions on the cache preset level for a specific role. It integrates in the admin toolbar, so if your user has access to that, it is a simple click on the preset to flush the caches you specified.

Description from project page:

> It ships with a predefined set of actions, but it's biggest strength lays in it's configuration, where one can build any number of custom presets to fit almost any need on both development and production environments.